# Converting char[][] to char[] in C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

Now I have a char array with the mac address stored in:

```
char mac_addr[6];
```

And I `sprintf` it into another char array:

```
char cmdstr[64];
sprintf(cmdstr, "MAC: %2x:%2x:%2x:%2x:%2x:%2x;",
mac_addr[0], mac_addr[1], mac_addr[2],
mac_addr[3], mac_addr[4], mac_addr[5]);
```

When I print `cmdstr`, it looks like this:

```
MAC: 08:10:76:10:26:21;
```

Then I send the `cmdstr` to a remote server, there is a parse function to parse this char array. After the `cmdstr` is parsed, the six parts separated by a `:` are stored in a multi char array:

```
char mac[6][10];
```

With:

```
char mac[0] = "08"
char mac[1] = "10"
char mac[2] = "76"
char mac[3] = "10"
char mac[4] = "26"
char mac[5] = "21"
```

Now, on the server side, how can I re-convert each part of the mac address to char and make it possible that the whole mac address can be stored in a char array like this?

```
char my_mac[6];
```

With:

```
my_mac[0] = '08'
my_mac[1] = '10'
my_mac[2] = '76'
my_mac[3] = '10'
my_mac[4] = '26'
my_mac[5] = '21'
```

Many thanks!

## Edit:

Sorry I think I described something wrongly, the text `'08'` itself should not stored in `my_mac[0]`. Actually when I gdb the program, I found that:

```
(gdb) p mac_addr[0]
$15 = 8 '\b'
(gdb) p mac_addr[1]
$16 = 16 '\020'
(gdb) p mac_addr[2]
$17 = 118 'v'
(gdb) p mac_addr[3]
$18 = 16 '\020'
(gdb) p mac_addr[4]
$19 = 38 '&'
(gdb) p mac_addr[5]
$20 = 33 '!'
```

I think I should convert the `mac[6][10]` to a char array just like above.

Comment: `'08'` is 2 characters. Do you want to store the number as text with 2 characters, or store the actual integer in the char variable?

Comment: @NeilKirk I think I need it be stored as text.

Comment: @Xing Why do you think so? `mac_addr` should contain actual integer for `%02x`, and you say "re-convert". Doesn't it mean you want to save the address to `my_mac` in the same format as `mac_addr`?

Comment: @Xing I got it, the needs to be stored as text should be come from "like this". And I think it cannot be acchieved since `char` can store only one character.

Comment: @MikeCAT yeah, think you are right, I should think about it more before I text any thing next time = =

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strtol` function in `stdlib.h`

```
char *dummy;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    my_mac[i] = strtol(mac[i], &dummy, 16);
}
```

Comment: This solution has no error checking. What if the incoming address was malformed?

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer. This code store like `my_mac[0] = 0x08`, not as specified `my_mac[0] = '08'`.

Comment: I think this actually IS what he wants, because he asks for the original char[6], and only the 6-byte binary form will fit in 6 chars.  His original char[6] was converted from binary to text with sprintf, and it looks like he just wants to deserialize back to this (binary) form. When he writes `my_mac[0] = '08'`, he probably means `my_mac[0] = '\x08'`

Comment: @MikeCAT `strtol()` just did the work. one more thing I did is converting hex to dec after the `strtol()` operation. Finally I got a char array as exactly same as `mac_addr[6]`, thanks!